# inserting and bolding a string in microsoft vba code

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is a snippet from code that I have created. It is working at the moment, but now I need to format the document. I am trying to make the third line in this code create an output that is bold, but I am stuck on how to do it.

**Snippet of code I am trying to edit:**

```
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 7))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 8))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter "Correct Answer is: " & (MyArray(iRow, 9))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 10))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 11))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 12))
```

**Here is the initial set up in the code in case you are wondering how the variables are set up:**

```
Dim objWord
Dim ObjNewDoc As Document

Dim RowsCount As Integer
Dim ColsCount As Integer

Dim rngFormat As Range

Dim MyArray() As String

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
```

I am trying to make the third line's output bold while leaving the remainder not bold. However, I am keep getting errors in VBA and am unsure how to overcome them.

On the Microsoft VBA reference website, it says the syntax is, "expression.Bold". I tried to insert it and it created an error obviously.

Comment: The MS help page for the InsertAfter method says that if the last paragraph mark of the document is included in the range then text is inserted at the end of the document rather than inserting a new paragraph.  By using ActiveDocument.Content so your inserts should be just extending the last paragraph of the document unless your text finishes with a Chr$(13).  So to help you further we need to know if the text you are inserting finished with a paragraph marker or not.

Comment: OH! I will check out the RubberDuck add in. So I am inserting a cell from a table. Each cell ends with an "end of cell" marker. The VBA script I created is taking the table contents into a new word document without the table format.

Comment: Since you're new to all this, some tips for getting efficient help on this site: 1) Provide a [mcve]. The code snippets you provide don't really show the entirety so that we can completely understand and test. If you've forgotten to include important information it wastes our time and yours. When you're getting errors, provide the error message *and* the line the triggers it. Don't expect others to run your code to find that out - we're professionals taking time out of our day to help you; no one here gets paid for that. Make it easy for us to understand and identify the problem.

Comment: When you reply to someone in comments you need to "ping" them by preceding the name with a `@`. Unlike many forums, there is no automatic notification if you don't "ping". If you forget, you may think people have "abandoned" you, but they simply won't know you've reacted to a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. As you enter text, you create a range that captures the line to be bolded. If we bolded it as the text is inserted, the following text would also be bold, so we wit until the end to apply the formatting:

```
Sub BoldOnePhrase()
    Dim oRange As Range

    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 7))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 8))

    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    oRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter "Correct Answer is: " & (MyArray(iRow, 9))
    oRange.MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=5

    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 10))
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter (MyArray(iRow, 11))

    oRange.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

If your array holds multi-word answers, you'll have to adjust the number of words to move the end of the range.

Comment: ohhhhhh I see now. I was entering the rang.font.bold before IRow 10 and the Dim oRange before Set.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways this can be approached - no one of them is "right" or "wrong" (assuming it works); what is used is a matter of preference. In any case, it's best solved working with one (or more) specific `Range` objects.

I prefer to work with a `Range` target, rather than using `InsertAfter` as I feel it gives me more control. Instead of `InsertAfter` I `Collapse` the `Range` object to its end-point. Think of it like pressing right-arrow to "collapse" a selection to a point.

This is done whenever the content needs to be handled differently. As long as strings are being written, they can all be inserted in one "line of code", as in the below example. When something needs to be done differently, the `Range` is collapsed and processing continues. This is done each time something needs to be different.

```
Sub InsertAndFormatContent
  Dim rng as Range
  Dim MyArray() As String
  Dim objNewDoc as Document

  'Populate MyArray here
  Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add()
  Set rng = objNewDoc.Content

  ' This code cannot run as MyArray is not populated!!!
  rng.Text = (MyArray(iRow, 7)) & (MyArray(iRow, 8)) & (MyArray(iRow, 9)) 
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rng.Text = "Correct answer is: " & (MyArray(iRow, 9))
  rng.Font.Bold = True
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rng.Text = (MyArray(iRow, 10)) & (MyArray(iRow,1)) & (MyArray(iRow, 12))                 
End Sub
```